prevent from displaying background notification
I use FCM in flutter my application. I want to receive my messages in background but I don't want to notification being displayed automatically; I want to create my own notification.
what should I do? can anyone help me?

Dont send the notification payload in the FCM message, send the data payload instead then in your FCM service in the app you create the notification

it should be handled from backend?

Notification messages are auto-handled by the system and displayed when the app is in the background. There is no way to change this behavior. To handle the display yourself, you'll want to send a data-only message

please read delivery options for FCM messages https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#delivery_options
